# Working With Multi Functional Array In Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6h7bedtL/) with all the data which crashes and doesn't run.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zpxsee7k/) with less data which runs but if you

```
console.log(`row ${g}, col ${i}`);
console.log(obj[pastWinners]);
```

It shows it is undefined.

I have a multi dimensional array in `Javascript` which runs some calculations for me. This `array` gets converted to a `object literal` and then after some data manipulation is changed to a `json object` and eventually a string.  The program works great!

I have to add 310 more lines to the multi dimensional array. When I do I get this error,

> index.html:331 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of
>   undefined

The original array looks like this,

```
var pastWinners = [
    [2, 9, 19, 23, 38, 40],
    [17, 25, 31, 35, 38, 43],
    [8, 10, 17, 30, 33, 43],
    [10, 17, 26, 28, 36, 43],
    [14, 20, 25, 28, 34, 41],
    [8, 13, 21, 23, 25, 43],
    [10, 11, 18, 24, 27, 30],
    [21, 22, 23, 26, 33, 39],
    [6, 21, 23, 29, 36, 40],
    [10, 12, 16, 21, 25, 42],
    [1, 11, 20, 27, 34, 37]
];
```

Notice the single digit numbers do not have a 0 in the tens place. But the new data looks like this,

```
[05, 07, 17, 18, 33, 35],
```

It does have a 0 in the tens place. I mention this because from aside from it being 310 more lines to the array that is the only difference. I have checked the data 50 times and there is nothing wrong with it.

Would a small difference like that make a difference to cause an error like this? It says the error is getting throws at line 331 in my program,

```
   var obj = {};

for (var g = 0; g < pastWinners.length; g++) {
    for (var i = 0, j = pastWinners.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (obj[pastWinners[g][i]] == undefined) {
            console.log(`row ${g}, col ${i}`);
            console.log(obj[pastWinners]);
        }
        if (obj[pastWinners[g][i]]) { //this is line 331
            obj[pastWinners[g][i]]++;
        } else {
            obj[pastWinners[g][i]] = 1;
        }
    }
}

var picks = [];
for (var numbs in obj) {
    picks.push([numbs, obj[numbs]])
    picks.sort(
        function(a, b) {
            return a[1] - b[1]
        }
    )
}

picks.reverse();
var topPicks = []

for (var winners = 0; winners < 6; winners++) {
    topPicks.push(picks[winners][0]);
}

var weekPicks = topPicks.toString();
console.log(weekPicks);
alert(weekPicks);
```

Does anyone see any reason this would happen when I add this data in? If it is an issue of the size of the array how can I handle this because I have a few thousand more lines of data to add in.

```
row 0, col 0
index.html:333 undefined
index.html:332 row 0, col 1
index.html:333 undefined
index.html:332 row 0, col 2
index.html:333 undefined
index.html:332 row 0, col 3
index.html:333 undefined
index.html:332 row 0, col 4
index.html:333 undefined
index.html:332 row 0, col 5
index.html:333 undefined
index.html:332 row 0, col 6
index.html:333 undefined
```

Comment: does 'obj' is defined?  does it have a value of '0' ?

Comment: why have you taken it as "obj[pastWinners[g][i]]" shouldn't it be just pastWinners[g][i]

Comment: there is a trailing comma  `,`   at the end of your data

Comment: No there is not. I am not showing all the data cause it would be too much to add ot here.

Comment: There is a fundamental flaw in your code - even with the small amount of data, you get `obj.undefined` having a value of 55 - which is `11x11` - `11x6` - as the way you are processing the data, you'll always be getting lots of `undefined` ... with the 321 lines of data you actually have, you'll end up with `obj.undefined: 3465`

Comment: I don't see why you think that. this program runs without errors till I add the new data. This one function is not the whole program.

Comment: I added my full program so you can see what I am doing.

Comment: Actually your right. When It runs with the less amount of data it still shows undefined. But it still works. I guess whats happening is since there are a lot more errors when you add more data it is causing the program to stop before the output. So What is it that is not defined I guess is what I am missing.

Comment: I think you'll need to post more of the data or more of the surrounding function for further help - the code works fine as is with the current data snippet.

Comment: I posted it all. And it works with just a few rows. I removed the 0s in the tens spot to make it all the same. The undefined is happening even with a little data. It just crashes the program when I add 300 lines. Basically the program counts the instances that a number appears. Then it takes the 6 numbers that appear the most and outputs them. I want to analyze thousands of numbers so If I can just figure out why the undefined is happening when I could them occurences I will be fine. But I cant figure that out or a different way to count the numbers.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eL6ad3Ld/ - well there is the isolated part of the code we're discussing and it's working fine. Perhaps you should create a fiddle with all of the data dumped in.

Comment: Ok good idea. I updated the question with two jsfiddles. One is the project with the data which will run. The other is with all the data and crashes before the output.

Comment: You're missing a comma in your data, check my answer below.

Comment: Jesus. Thanks man. It doesn't crash but for me the first number prints out as undefined still. But it does show the other five numbers.

Comment: That's because you're not `console.log`ing the first number... you're trying to print out a full array as a property of `obj` which doesn't exist. To print the first number it should be `obj[pastWinners[g][i]]` rather than `obj[pastWinners]`.

Comment: Ok thank you for all of your help. I will work on fixing that last problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By adding a `console.log(g)` of what index you were up to when the error happens, this is actually an issue with your data:

```
[2, 7, 8, 9, 27, 38],
[9, 12, 17, 24, 26, 41]
[18, 20, 21, 31, 40, 44],
```

You are missing a comma after the 176th index. https://jsfiddle.net/6h7bedtL/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try to print the array in the console when you get undefined and check your array size in the log.

```
for (var g = 0; g < pastWinners.length; g++) {
    for (var i = 0, j = pastWinners.length; i < j; i++) {
        if (obj[pastWinners[g][i]] == undefined){
         console.log(`row ${g}, col ${i}`);
         console.log(obj[pastWinners]);
        }
        if (obj[pastWinners[g][i]]) { //this is line 331
            obj[pastWinners[g][i]]++;
        } else {
            obj[pastWinners[g][i]] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey man I added the output from the console.log you provided to my question. Yes it does show undefined but I am not really sure what to gather from that.

Comment: I updated my question with the full program so you can see what I am doing.

Comment: Well, it looks like all the data inside is undefined. I don't know the algorithm you are using but try to debug from developer panel section source (if using chrome). If every time obj[pastWinners[g][i]] is undefined that means it always goes to the else condition. And if your error is thrown in the If statement it means at some point you are trying to index undefined. That means g is going to a line outside pastWinners and pastWinners[g] is undefined and you try to index it with pastWinners[g][i]. Just debug it and see what is happening

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently:

a. change the second loop...

b. define obj

```
var pastWinners = [
    [2, 9, 19, 23, 38, 40],
    [17, 25, 31, 35, 38, 43],
    [8, 10, 17, 30, 33, 43],
    [10, 17, 26, 28, 36, 43],
    [14, 20, 25, 28, 34, 41],
    [8, 13, 21, 23, 25, 43],
    [10, 11, 18, 24, 27, 30],
    [21, 22, 23, 26, 33, 39],
    [6, 21, 23, 29, 36, 40],
    [10, 12, 16, 21, 25, 42],
    [1, 11, 20, 27, 34, 37], 
];
var obj=[];
for (var g = 0; g < pastWinners.length; g++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < pastWinners[g].length; i++) {
        if (obj[pastWinners[g][i]]) { //this is line 331
            obj[pastWinners[g][i]]++;
        } else {
            obj[pastWinners[g][i]] = 1;
        }
    }
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: When I try this way I get index.html:329 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined(…) But I do not understand why is the length of pastWinners undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Also you should check for the existence of `pastWinners[g]`  before you loop through it or try to access a child array using

`if (pastWinners[g] != null) {`

The reason for this is that if  `pastWinners[g]` for some reason is not defined, then your script will attempt to do this:

`undefined[i]`  or get the value of [i] from undefined -- which it cant because undefined is not an array -- which breaks your script

```js
var pastWinners = [
  [2, 9, 19, 23, 38, 40],
  [17, 25, 31, 35, 38, 43],
  [8, 10, 17, 30, 33, 43],
  [10, 17, 26, 28, 36, 43],
  [14, 20, 25, 28, 34, 41],
  [8, 13, 21, 23, 25, 43],
  [10, 11, 18, 24, 27, 30],
  [21, 22, 23, 26, 33, 39],
  [6, 21, 23, 29, 36, 40],
  [10, 12, 16, 21, 25, 42],
  [1, 11, 20, 27, 34, 37],
];
for (var g = 0; g < pastWinners.length; g++) {

  if (pastWinners[g] != null) {  // check for valid item

    for (var i = 0, j = pastWinners[g].length; i < j; i++) {

      if (pastWinners[g][i] != null) {
        pastWinners[g][i]++;
      } else {
        pastWinners[g][i] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(pastWinners);
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly

```
 for (var i = 0, j = pastWinners.length; i < j; i++)
```

should be

```
for (var i = 0, j = pastWinners[g].length; i < j; i++)
```

The array items in `pastWinners` do not have the length of `pastwinners` :D

Comment: Thanks but no this does not work either. Man I just don't even know where to go. This is really annoying.